# Representations of group $G=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I need to find all in-equivalent irreducible  representation of a group $G \equiv \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $

I know that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic finite group. So its representations are equivalent to unitary representations $U_p$.

So is it true that all the representations of $g$ are just the direct sum of representations of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: In general the irreducible representations of a direct product are "outer" tensor products of representations of the factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $G$ is abelian, the irreducible representations (over $\Bbb C$) have to be 1-dimensional.  The possible actions are governed by the following:

- Note that the group action is determined by the action of any two generating elements.
- Since the representation is 1-dimensional, any element $g$'s action is just multiplication by some scalar $\lambda_g \in \Bbb C$.
- The action of any element $g$ is constrained by $g^p = 1$.

It is left to the reader to piece this information to get concrete realizations of the $p^2$ irreducible representations.